# eclipse:eclipse to generate "Maven project" in using eclipse:eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven java project pom,
When running eclipse:eclipse maven will generate an "ordinary" java project
Is there a way to tell it to generate "maven java project" (I have to go to configure -> convert to Maven project every time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eclipse:eclipse is long deprecated. Use m2e (included in modern eclipse).

Just create a new oroject and use Maven project as the type.

Comment: or available from the Marketplace.  Import as an existing Maven project.